# Get IRC Command response

Tags: command, response, irc

I want to run an IRC Command, and get the response for it for bots.

Is there any way to do this?

for example, I want to get the result of "NAMES #channel" or "WHO #channel u"

Comment: maybe getting latest given data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for 353 and 366 replies (for NAMES), and 354 and 315 for WHO.

For instance, when using NAMES:

```
(outgoing) NAMES #channel
(incoming) :wilhelm.freenode.net 353 botnick = #channel :user1 user2 user3 @user4
(incoming) :wilhelm.freenode.net 366 botnick #channel :End of /NAMES list.
```

And similarily when using WHO:

```
(outgoing) WHO #channel
(incoming) :wilhelm.freenode.net 354 botnick #channel ident host sendak.freenode.net nick H 0 nick :realname
[…]
(incoming) :wilhelm.freenode.net 315 botnick #channel :End of /WHO list.
```

Comment: Thank you, Valentin Loerentz

Comment: They are called “numerics”. Here is a mostly exhaustive list: https://www.alien.net.au/irc/irc2numerics.html